# Java program to insert value in Aerospike database not working

Tags: java, database, aerospike, nosql

I have written a java program to insert an integer and a double in aerospike database. Here is the code snippet

```
import com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient;
import com.aerospike.client.Bin;
import com.aerospike.client.Key;
import com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy;

public class Test{

public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        AerospikeClient client = new AerospikeClient("192.168.140.62", 3000);

        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
            try {
                WritePolicy writePolicy =  new WritePolicy();
                Key key = new Key("test" , "myset", "mykey");
                double randomDouble = Math.random();
                Bin bin1 = new Bin("ID",i);
                Bin bin2 = new Bin("Value",randomDouble);

                client.put(writePolicy,key,bin1,bin2);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
        client.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The problem is the above code snippet is neither inserting any data nor throwing any errors. Please advise. 
PS: I am new to aerospike

Comment: I have no clue about it but it seems instead of put you schould use add, check example https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/examples/src/com/aerospike/examples/Add.java

Comment: What error do you get when you try to execute this ?

Comment: Hey the program runs fine, I was actually firing a wrong query in aql - my bad.Is there a way to read all the records of a particular set at one go?